# Find word in string, and increment the integer that comes after

Tags: php, regex, system, contacts

it's for my contact system.

Subject of mail could be: `Hello Friend.` and `RE^2 Hello Friend`.

I need code to find if the subject have `RE^{int} {subject}`, if it have than make it `RE^{++int} {subject}`.

If not: than make it `RE^2 {subject}`.

```
<?php
    preg_match('/^RE\^(\d)*$/', $mail->subject , $m);

    if (empty ($m)) {
        $newSubject = 'RE^2 '.$mail->subject;
    } else {
        $reNum = $m[1]+1;
        // How to edit the subject to 'RE^{++num} {$mail->subject}' ?
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please show what attempts you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can use REGEX with preg_match to find you number like the following:

```
$str = "RE^3 Hello Friend";
preg_match( '/RE\^(\d*)/', $str , $m);
print_r( $m );

$number = $m[ 1 ]
```

The end result could be something like:

```
$subject = "Hello Friend";
preg_match( '/RE\^(\d*)/', $subject , $m);

if ( empty ( $m )  ) 
    $newSubject = "RE^2 Hello Friend";
else{
    $number = $m[ 1 ] + 1;
    $newSubject = "RE^$number Hello Friend";
}
echo $newSubject;
```

---

To answer your comment here is the changed code:

```
$subject = "Hello AbuRomaissae";

if ( !preg_match( '/RE\^(\d*)/', $subject , $m)  ) 
    $newSubject = "RE^2 $subject";
else{
    $number = $m[ 1 ] + 1;
    $newSubject = "RE^$number ".preg_replace( '/RE\^(\d*) /', "", $subject);
}
echo $newSubject;
```

Comment: Oh thanks you. Last question, how I can change `Hello Friend` to the subject string?
$newSubject = "RE^$number Hello Friend";

Comment: @user3025333, what do you mean by: change Hello Friend to the subject string ?

Comment: Great! Thanks! Only one thing. It's okay for RE^9, but what about RE^10? 2 Digits? Thanks man...

Comment: @user3025333 I've tried it and it worked fine, there should be no problem related to the digit numbers, if found any leave me comment :)

Comment: @user3025333 I've updated my answer, there were a small mistake  in the first part that I corrected

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `preg_replace_callback` so that you can use a function to handle the replacement.

```
$subject = 'Hello Friend';
$subject = 'RE^2 Hello Friend';

$subject = preg_replace_callback('/RE\^(\d*)/', 'myFunc', $subject);
function myFunc($matches) {
  $x = ++$matches[0];
  return $x;
}

if (!preg_match('/RE\^\d*/', $subject)) { //if "RE^\d" is missing, add "RE^2"
  $subject = "RE^2 {$subject}";
}

echo $subject; //'RE^3 Hello Friend'
```

Comment: It will make any number to ++...

Comment: @user3025333 isn't that what you asked for? lol

Comment: if his subject is something like, `Hi5 Friend` it will become `Hi6 Friend` this is not what he wanted, but I liked you way :)

Comment: @user3025333 see my updated answer. It will only increment the number following "RE^" and will add "RE^2" to the subject if it is missing.